# как получить по id vk имя и фамилию

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Получил user_id, но не знаю как по нему получить имя и фамилию пользователя

```
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);

        VKApiGetDialogResponse getDialogResponse = ((VKApiGetDialogResponse)response.parsedModel);
        final  VKList<VKApiDialog> list= getDialogResponse.items;

        ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
        for (VKApiDialog msg : list){

            users.add(String.valueOf(msg.message.user_id));
            messages.add(msg.message.body);
        }
        listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,users,messages,list));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполняете запрос [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get), в котором передаете `id` пользователя и получаете список результатов из которого выбираете первый.

Comment: возвращает null, а вот friends.get() по тому же id возвращает все как надо.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него код выполнения users.get